# Registering a third party class in Autofac whose constructor take in values from another service

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I am working with `IQueueClient` interface in `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` namespace.

Here is my code

```
public HomeControllerBL(IApplicationSettings appSettings)
{
    _appSettings = appSettings;
}
```

and here is my IApplicationSettings Interface

```
public interface IApplicationSettings
{
    string GetServiceBusConnectionString();    
    string GetQueueName();
}
```

Now for creating an object of `QueueClient`

```
IQueueClient queueClient = new QueueClient(appSettings.GetServiceBusConnectionString(), appSettings.GetQueueName());
```

So `IQueueClient` has a dependency on `IApplicationSettings` .

Is there a way I can register both `IQueueClient` and `IApplicationSettings` with Autofac as a dependency for `HomeControllerBL`

Something on these Lines :-

```
builder.RegisterType<ApplicationSettings>()
    .As<IApplicationSettings>()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.RegisterType<QueueClient>()
    .As<IQueueClient>().WithParameters(new List<Parameter>() { How to access Applicationsettings methods here ???  })
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Reference [Lambda Expression Components](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/registration.html#lambda-expression-components)

> Reflection is a pretty good default choice for component creation. Things get messy, though, when component creation logic goes beyond a simple constructor call.
>
> Autofac can accept a delegate or lambda expression to be used as a component creator:

```
builder.Register(c => {
    IApplicationSettings appSettings = c.Resolve<IApplicationSettings>();
    IQueueClient queueClient = new QueueClient(appSettings.GetServiceBusConnectionString(), appSettings.GetQueueName());
    return queueClient;
})
.As<IQueueClient>()
.InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

> The parameter `c` provided to the expression is the *component context* (an `IComponentContext` object) in which the component is being created. You can use this to resolve other values from the container to assist in creating your component. **It is important to use this rather than a closure to access the container** so that deterministic disposal and nested containers can be supported correctly.

So now the controller can depend on `IQueueClient` explicitly

```
private readonly IQueueClient queueClient;

public HomeControllerBL(IQueueClient queueClient) {
    this.queueClient = queueClient;
}
```